# Extracting features from High Resolution mosaic (tiff)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, feature-extraction

[image]

I have a very high resolution map(tif) i.e. drone image as shown in the image.

Is there any way we could extract features including building and road etc. from high resolution image?

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to use [image classification](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/what-is-image-classification-.htm) for extracting features.

There are two types of image classification. Supervised and [unsupervised](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/iso-cluster-unsupervised-classification.htm). I think you need to use supervised classification

You can use [Image Classification Toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/image-classification-using-spatial-analyst.htm). Use [Image Analysis window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-the-image-analysis-window.htm) for image preprocessing.

The below flowchart is a reference for users to classify Images in ArcGIS.

[image]

2. [Creating features using raster snapping and the editing feature construction tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/creating-features-using-raster-snapping-and-the-editing-feature-construction-tools.htm): You can use the Create Features window construction tools and Editor toolbar sketch construction methods tool to generate features to trace rasters and create features.
3. [Creating features with the Vectorization Trace tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/creating-features-with-the-vectorization-trace-too.htm):  The Vectorization Trace tool is designed for tracing connected raster cells. Place the tool at an appropriate start location in the raster and click to begin the tracing process. The Vectorization Trace tool automatically follows the centerline of the raster cells based on the direction in which you point the tool's arrow and subsequently generates vector features.
4. [Drone2map](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/drone2map/) is a new software for interacting drone with ArcGIS products. I don't know this software is suitable for your project.